# Change one attribute value of a script so it effects all gameObjects that this script is attached to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I change one or two attribute values of a script so that it effects all the gameObjects that this script is attached to?

For example making attributes SphereSmall and SphereBig global

```
 public Vector3 SphereSmall = new Vector3 (0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
 public Vector3 SphereBig = new Vector3 (0.0015f, 0.0015f, 0.0015f);
```

Two gameObjects has this script attached to and I changed the attribute of public variables SphereSmall and SphereBig on one GameObject. I want this value to be changed in second GameObject as well.

Comment: Please provide more information, it is not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: I have edited it and posted more info

Comment: Is your goal to instantiate SphereSmall and SphereBig **one time** and make them accessible from all the GameObjects or to instantiate them **for every object** that runs that script, but with the same arguments?

Comment: Mohammed, more program context please - for me it is still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Okay for example, you have a script that is attached to 10 gameObjects and you want to change the value of a variable. But you do not want to go to each gameObject to change it. You just go to one GameObject and that gets reflected in all gameObjects. The value must be changed from the inspector window.

Comment: You can have static variables on classes, so the script you add can have a static value that changes across all instances. However there are limitations and things to consider

Comment: @BugFinder I thought of that but I cannot alter static variable values in the inspector window.

Comment: To be fair you never said you needed to do it in the inspector, you just said you needed to change it

Comment: Yea I am sorry about that I had not mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add [ExecuteInEditMode] to your script so it runs while the editor is running. From there you could check if the values are being changed and then update them. Something like this:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  public int myValue;
  private int oldValue;

  void Update ()
  {
    if (oldValue != myValue)
    {
      MyScript[] objects = FindObjectsOfType<MyScript>();

      foreach(MyScript myObject in objects)
      {
        myObject.myValue = myValue
      }

      oldValue = myValue;
    }
  }
}
```

This isn't best practice though so I would recommend looking into using prefab variants instead.

Comment: Thank you. I created a gameObject with a different script that has same attributes and the script that is attached to other gameObjects have this different script referenced to.

Comment: This might lead to problems since all the instances of `MyScript` will be running this  ... so which one will be allowed to change the other ones before it gets reset by any of the other instances? [TestSubject's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56561953/7111561) using either a `ScriptableObject` or a prefab is more apropriate for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to unity as well, but here are some solutions:

1) If you're talking about multiple instances of the same object, simply create a prefab out of that object and update the properties of the prefab.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingPrefabs.html

2) If you're talking about instances of different objects, you can try using the multi-select functionality of the unity editor, this will let you edit all common properties. This is easy if you have lower number if instances and are grouped under a parent object in the Hierarchy pane.

3) If you're talking about instances of different objects and you don't mind seeing the effect of your updates only at run-time: you can try using the ScriptableObject class:

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class CommonObjectProperties : ScriptableObject
{
    public Vector3 SphereSmall = new Vector3(1, 0.001f, 0.001f);
    public Vector3 SphereBig = new Vector3(0.0015f, 0.0015f, 0.0015f);
}
```

After you create this script, go to Assets > Create > Common Object Properties:

[image]

Now you can use this ScriptableObject instance to add the common values to your objects and after you update them inside the ScriptableObject instance, they will update across all objects.

ObjectScript is the MonoBehaviour script to put on your objects:

```
public class ObjectScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CommonObjectPropertis commonProps;
    public Vector3 ObjectScriptSmallSphere;

    private void Start()
    {
        ObjectScriptSmallSphere = commonProps.SphereSmall;   
    }
}
```

How it should look in the designer:
[image]

I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to do this, best of luck!

Comment: This answer is more appropriate! You could still combine the `ScriptableObject` with `[ExecuteInEditMode]` in order to see the effects already in edit mode